# MVVM with Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

Do you know where can I find a detailed documentation/tutorial on MVVM Light and Windows Phone 7 ? 
I only found short explanations et some very basic tutorials.

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [getting started guide](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) which should be a good starting point. It contains links to lots of useful articles.